# Why can't I pass the hidden hashtable test cases?

Tags: c, debugging, hashtable

**Coalesce Hashing in C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TABLESIZE 37
#define PRIME     13

enum Marker {EMPTY,USED};

typedef struct _slot{
   int key;
   enum Marker indicator;
   int next;
} HashSlot;
```

```
int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[]);
int HashFind(int key, HashSlot hashTable[]);
```

```
int hash(int key)
{
   return (key % TABLESIZE);
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int opt;
    int i;
    int key;
    int index;
    HashSlot hashTable[TABLESIZE];

    for(i=0;i<TABLESIZE;i++){
        hashTable[i].next = -1;
        hashTable[i].key = 0;
        hashTable[i].indicator = EMPTY;
    }

    printf("============= Hash Table ============\n");
    printf("|1. Insert a key to the hash table  |\n");
    printf("|2. Search a key in the hash table  |\n");
    printf("|3. Print the hash table            |\n");
    printf("|4. Quit                            |\n");
    printf("=====================================\n");

    printf("Enter selection: ");
    scanf("%d",&opt);
    while(opt>=1 && opt <=3){
        switch(opt){
        case 1:
            printf("Enter a key to be inserted:\n");
            scanf("%d",&key);
            index = HashInsert(key,hashTable);
            if(index <0)
                printf("Duplicate key\n");
            else if(index < TABLESIZE)
                printf("Insert %d at index %d\n",key, index);
            else
                printf("Table is full.\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a key for searching in the HashTable:\n");
            scanf("%d",&key);
            index = HashFind(key, hashTable);

            if(index!=-1)
                printf("%d is found at index %d.\n",key,index);
            else
                printf("%d is not found.\n",key);
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("index:\t key \t next\n");
            for(i=0;i<TABLESIZE;i++) printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",i, hashTable[i].key,hashTable[i].next);
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter selection: ");
        scanf("%d",&opt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
    int index=hash(key),inIndex=0,count=0;

    if(hashTable[index].indicator == EMPTY) // first slot empty
    {
        hashTable[index].key = key;
        hashTable[index].next = -1;
        hashTable[index].indicator = USED;   
        return index;       
    }
    else // slot used
    {
        while(1)
        {   
            while(hashTable[count].indicator == USED) // all slots used
            {
                count++;
                if(count == TABLESIZE)
                {
                    return count; // return table is full
                }
            }

            if(index<TABLESIZE) // index slot < TABLESIZE
            {
                for(index=hash(key);index<TABLESIZE;index++) // iterate thru 
                {
                    if(hashTable[index].key == key)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    
                    if (hashTable[index].next == -1 && hashTable[index].indicator == USED && 
                    hash(key)==hash(hashTable[index].key) )//save the last point where it has the same mod value
                    {
                        inIndex = index;
                    }

                    else if(hashTable[index].indicator == EMPTY)
                    {
                        hashTable[inIndex].next = index; // lastpoint.next = currentindex
                        hashTable[index].key = key;
                        hashTable[index].next = -1;
                        hashTable[index].indicator = USED; 
                        return index; // return insertion value
                    }  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(index=hash(index);index<TABLESIZE;index++) // if index > TABLESIZE
                {
                    if(hashTable[index].key == key)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }

                    if (hashTable[index].next == -1 && hashTable[index].indicator == USED && 
                    hash(key)==hash(hashTable[index].key) ) //save the last point where it has the same mod value
                    {
                        inIndex = index;
                    }
                    else if(hashTable[index].indicator == EMPTY)
                    {
                        hashTable[inIndex].next = index; // latestmodvalue.next = currentindex
                        hashTable[index].key = key;
                        hashTable[index].next = -1;
                        hashTable[index].indicator = USED; 
                        return index; // return insertion value
                    }  
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if(HashFind(key,hashTable) == index) // if key cant be found
        return -1;
}
```

```
int HashFind(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
    int index;
    index = hash(key);

    if(hashTable[index].key == 0) return -1; // if empty slot , return -1
    else if(hashTable[index].key == key) // if found key , return index
    {
        return index;
    }
    else
    {
        while(hashTable[index].key!=key && index!=-1) // find the link , then find the key
        {
            index = hashTable[index].next;
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

The idea is to implement a hash table with a combination of closed addressing and linear probing. I have tried multiple test cases that I came up with such as dealing with negatives or accessing an item that is not in the HashTable, nothing seems to pass the hidden test case. Passed the sample test case though. Is there something that I am overlooking on?

Given test case :

Insert key : 1 2 5 41 42  4 10(search then insert)

Search key: 4 10(Display DNE)

### Output from my Code

```
============= Hash Table ============
|1. Insert a key to the hash table  |
|2. Search a key in the hash table  |
|3. Print the hash table            |
|4. Quit                            |
=====================================
Enter selection: 1 Enter a key to be inserted:
Insert 1 at index 1
Enter selection: 1 Enter a key to be inserted:
Insert 2 at index 2
Enter selection: 1 Enter a key to be inserted:
Insert 5 at index 5
Enter selection: 1 Enter a key to be inserted:
Insert 41 at index 4
Enter selection: 1 Enter a key to be inserted:
Insert 42 at index 6
Enter selection: 3
index:   key:    next:
0   0   -1
1   1   -1
2   2   -1
3   0   -1
4   41  -1
5   5   6
6   42  -1
7   0   -1
8   0   -1
9   0   -1
10  0   -1
11  0   -1
12  0   -1
13  0   -1
14  0   -1
15  0   -1
16  0   -1
17  0   -1
18  0   -1
19  0   -1
20  0   -1
21  0   -1
22  0   -1
23  0   -1
24  0   -1
25  0   -1
26  0   -1
27  0   -1
28  0   -1
29  0   -1
30  0   -1
31  0   -1
32  0   -1
33  0   -1
34  0   -1
35  0   -1
36  0   -1
Enter selection: 1 Enter a key to be inserted:
Insert 4 at index 7
Enter selection: 2 Enter a key for searching in the HashTable:
4 is found at index 7.
Enter selection: 2 Enter a key for searching in the HashTable:
10 is not found.
Enter selection: 1 Enter a key to be inserted:
Insert 10 at index 10
Enter selection: 3
index:   key:   next:
0   0   -1
1   1   -1
2   2   -1
3   0   -1
4   41  7
5   5   6
6   42  -1
7   4   -1
8   0   -1
9   0   -1
10  10  -1
11  0   -1
12  0   -1
13  0   -1
14  0   -1
15  0   -1
16  0   -1
17  0   -1
18  0   -1
19  0   -1
20  0   -1
21  0   -1
22  0   -1
23  0   -1
24  0   -1
25  0   -1
26  0   -1
27  0   -1
28  0   -1
29  0   -1
30  0   -1
31  0   -1
32  0   -1
33  0   -1
34  0   -1
35  0   -1
36  0   -1
```

Comment: Please provide more information, details, context. Maybe show the non-hidden test cases and their results from your program, as well as any test case you invented yourself, to allow finding your blind spot. This is a non-trivial program and you should not expect that users read the code and understand everything from it (though there probably are some who can ...). The more users you help into the topic and the better and deeper you help them into it, the better your chances at an answer. Also, making a one-piece [mre] instead of the set of code fragments might help.

Comment: You could also try to make the program spot anything out of the usual and thereby help you. For that you should e.g. not ignore the return values of scanf and insert debugging outputs (or use a debugger) to observe whether everything is progressing exactly as you imagine. This might find cases which by chance work but are actually slightly off. Which in turn might be were the hidden test-cases fail.

Comment: What is a hidden test case? The three fundamental questions are
1. What do you do?
2. What happens?
3. What did you expect to happen?